# React Hooksの繰り返し内での使用

Tags: reactjs

React Hooksはifやforの内部では使用できないという制約があります。
そうすると、検索結果を一覧表示するようなテーブルの行の中ではReact Hooksを一切使用できないということになるのでしょうか。
テーブルの各行がコンポーネントになっている場合、各行に表示するデータおよびそれを更新するための関数を与えるためにはprops経由で渡す必要があるのでしょうか。

Comment: 具体例があるとより正確に回答できるかもしれません。とりあえず、「React Hooksを使用しているコンポーネント」をループで表示したりするのは問題ないです。あくまで関数コンポーネントの定義の内部において、ifやforの中でuseState()などを呼び出すのが禁止されています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

react hooks は、 functional component の中で使用しますが、その component を定義する関数の中で、 hook に関する関数(useState や useEffect)は、毎回決まった順番で呼び出してください、というのがその制約の言わんとすることだったと記憶しています。

useState の戻り値である setXxx は、繰り返しの中だろうと何であろうと実行できる認識です。